# Printing series in a single line

Tags: c#, series

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTkMu.jpg)

> How can I display the result in a single line?
>   I tried replacing every WriteLine to Write but the output did not change.
>   I also tried replacing i <= n to i < n but the output did not change.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n = 0, i;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the limit");
        n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 != 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", 1);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", 0);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Try changing `i <= n` to `i < n`

Comment: `WriteLine` != `Write` (Please have a look at the documentation for `Console` to see what methods it offers to write out stuff in different ways)

Comment: did not help by changing  i <=n to i < n

Comment: I changed WriteLine to Write but did not help.

Comment: Of course `Write` helps with the problem explained in the question. If you do not clearly specify what your problem is and if you don't clearly specify the expected result, well... We can only work with what you have written in your question. And `Write` will help with regard to what is explained in the question. If that is not what you want, **edit** and improve your question to more accurately explain your problem (do **NOT** explain here in the comments; update your question)

Comment: hey elgonzo now see my question. and my result also.

Comment: Move the the ReadKey outside the loop...

Comment: Thankyou dude it helped. It was just a silly mistake. Sorry for troubles.